# Approximation of $\sigma$-finite Borel measures by equivalent finite measures

Tags: measure-theory, borel-sets

Let $(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d),\mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite Borel measure on $d$-dimensional Euclidean space.  Can one always construct a sequence of finite *equivalent* measures $\left\{\mu_n\right\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ on $(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d))$ such that
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{d\mu_n}{d\mu} \uparrow 1.
$$

**Motivation:**
This is true for both the Lebesgue measure and the counting measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$ by taking
$\frac{d\mu_n}{d\mu}(x)\triangleq \begin{cases}
e^{-q_n\min\{\|x\|,\frac1{\|x\|}\}}&:\, x\neq 0\\
1 &: \, x =0 
\end{cases}
$, where $q_n$ runs over $\mathbb{Q}\cap(0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite there is a $\mu$-integrable function $f$ with $0<f\le 1$. For an increasing sequence $A_n$ with $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N} A_n=\mathbb R^d$ define densities $f_n=I_{A_n}+fI_{A_n^c}$. Then $\mu_n=f_n\cdot \mu$ are equivalent finite measures whose densities converge to $1$.

Comment: But how to show that such a function exists (ie the bounded away from 0 part)?

Comment: If $A_n$ are as in the answer set $B_1=A_1$, $B_n=A_n\setminus A_{n-1}$, and $f=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty c_n 1_{B_n}$ with suitable $c_n>0$, so that $\int f d \mu= \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty c_n \mu(B_n)<\infty$.

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with the topology of $\mathbb R^d$. It holds for every $\sigma$-finite measure space.

Comment: Yes I had noticed that; thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Let $(E,\cal{E},\mu)$ be a measure space and $\mu$ a not finite $\sigma$-finite  measure on $\cal{E}$. Then there is a sequence $E_n$ of $E_n \in \cal{E}$ with $E_n \uparrow E$ and $0 < \mu(E_n) < \mu(E_{n+1}) < \infty$. Let $a_1 := \mu(E_1)$ and $a_n := \mu(E_n \setminus E_{n-1})$ for $n > 1$. Let $\mu_n(A) := \mu(A \cap E_n) + \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty 2^{-k} / \mu(E_k \setminus E_{k-1}) \cdot \mu(A \cap (E_k \setminus E_{k-1}))$ for $A \in \cal{E}$. Then each $\mu_n$ is finite, equivalent to $\mu$ and $\mu_n \uparrow \mu$.

Comment: Edited after reading Jochen Wengenroths answer. I ommited the topological assumtions.